# How to add 'Open folder as root' to Files right-click context menu?

Tags: pantheon-files

I want to be able to quickly open a new window of Pantheon Files with root to do administrative tasks (e.g. edit .desktop files). So when I right-click on a folder icon it would be nice to have an option to "Open folder as root" similar to the already present "Open in Terminal".

Comment: My only suggestion would be to right-click and open in terminal, and do any root work there.

Comment: Required: Do NOT edit things as root unless you are sure you know what you are doing, and not just following instructions off the internet.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92494/32012

Comment: @Tim As far as I remember the question actually got downvoted before I added the disclaimer...

Comment: Disagree. It's not *their fault*, this site should appeal to all demographics, hence newbies **should** be warned. And also reminded that there might be better / securer / easier ways to achieve what they aim to do.

Answer (score 6):

It is already there for me in the dock:

[image]

However, if you can't see that, use `sudo`:

```
sudo -i pantheon-files
```

---

You want to be able to jump to a `sudo` instance of the current folder. It's a little roundabout, but you could right click, open in terminal:

[image]

Then run this command:

```
sudo -i pantheon-files $(pwd)
```

you could even set up an alias for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also helpful. But I would like to have a direct link in "Open in >", which should be possible with a file in /usr/share/contractor (but I'm not sure what to actually put there because gksu is deprecated).

Comment: You can take pkexec instead of gksu.

Comment: @Tim please use pkexec instead of sudo. Sudo and gksudo are not recommending for running apps. They are not as secure as pkexec.

Comment: @DanielForé what do you mean by secure? 2 months ago, sudo -i was the recommended method...

Comment: @Tim gksudo is *deprecated* and should not be used. It has been replaced by pkexec. Policykit is the standard for escalating privileges for graphical apps. From the pkexec docs "The environment that PROGRAM will run [in], will be set to a minimal known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking pkexec."

Comment: @DanielForé I know about gksudo, but what's the issue with `sudo -i`?

Comment: @Tim same deal. Pkexec is what should be used. No idea about the Ubuntu answer, but as always this is not Ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/78352/186134 suggests they are much of a muchness, and the bit you quoted doesn't really clear it up for me - what would pkexec protect me from that sudo doesn't, and what are the disadvantages?

Comment: @DanielForé On top of that, `pkexec` doesn't seem to be configured for graphical interface by default, so suggesting that is used seems to be a roundabout solution to a maybe problem.

Comment: @DanielForé What makes you claim that sudo is “not as secure as pkexec”? You've said that gksudo was deprecated (so is it just gksudo or also sudo that you don't like), and you quote a passage from the pkexec documentation which doesn't seem relevant since sudo has the same feature.

Comment: @Gilles, Tim we have a policykit policy written for Files already to run it using pkexec. In the interest of not mucking up the comments here, perhaps this should be its own new question. It's not about "liking" anything. gksu is deprecated upstream by its own developers. From polkit docs "In contrast to systems such as sudo, it does not grant root permission to an entire process, but rather allows a finer level of control of centralized system policy." You don't jump straight to sudo, just to a "user" that has higher filesystem permissions. It doesn't grant the app other sudo rights.

Comment: @DanielForé Okay, fair enough but that doesn't accept locational arguments by the look of things: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1474124 and http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/442/3

Comment: @Tim Sure, but that doesn't mean we should recommend less secure methods imo. The proper thing to do is just to open Files with the built-in "Admin" shortcut and navigate back to where you want to be.

Comment: @DanielForé but that's wasting people's time... Why? And why do you say "secure" - I'm really not convinced that opening patheon-files with sudo over pkexec is going to do anything bad...

Comment: @DanielForé I've opened a new question http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/453/in-plain-english-what-about-sudo-makes-it-less-secure-than-pkexec it may be easier than using the comments.

Answer (score 6):

We need to create a `.contract` file in `/usr/share/contractor`.

Run these two commands:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/contractor/openasroot.contract
sudo nano /usr/share/contractor/openasroot.contract
```

Then paste in the following:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Open folder as root
Icon=pantheon-files
Description=Open current folder as root privilege
MimeType=inode;
Exec=gksudo pantheon-files
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

[Source](http://www.unixmen.com/add-open-folder-root-elementary-os-right-click-menu/)

---

Just a reminder, be careful when you have root access - bad bad things can happen.

Comment: `pkexec panthen-files` works in the terminal, but it doesn't work in a `.contract`... at least for me

Comment: That's probably the reason why elementary OS is using the shellscript `/usr/bin/pantheon-files-pkexec` for *New Window As Administrator*

Comment: `/usr/bin/pantheon-files-pkexec` doesn't process any arguments, that's why it doesn't work properly in a `.contract`. Modifying `pantheon-files-pkexec` to accept arguments or, better, creating a new script might solve this problem.

Comment: Related bug report: [#1474124 pantheon-files-pkexec does not accept arguments](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1474124) (old link was broken). Not marking as accepted because there seems to be no safe & working solution right now...

Answer (score 0):

[This script](https://github.com/quassy/elementary-scripts/blob/master/enable-openasroot.sh#L5) works on elementary OS Loki to add "Open folder as root" option via `pkexec`.

To use it, first create a contractor entry:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/contractor/folder-openasroot.contract
gksudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/contractor/folder-openasroot.contract
```

Then edit it like this:

```
[Contractor Entry]  
Name=Open folder as root  
Icon=pantheon-files  
Description=Open folder as root  
MimeType=inode;  
Exec=pantheon-files-pkexec %U  
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

And then via terminal run this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "#!/bin/sh
pkexec \"/usr/bin/pantheon-files\" \"\$@\"" > /usr/bin/pantheon-files-pkexec'
```